# Filter tables beeing shown on combobox

Tags: c#, sql

I´ve been working on an app that lists all tables from sql database to allow some editing.
But not all tables should be visible. 
Can anyone tell how to filter my query so that it only shows the desired tables?

the code i have now is:

```
con.Open();
using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES", con))
{
    using (SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader())
    {
        tabelas.Items.Clear();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            tabelas.Items.Add((string)reader["TABLE_NAME"]);
        }
    }
}
```

I think it should be something like

```
SELECT TABLES I WANT TO SHOW FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

But in the `reader` what should i insert?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: That's wrong , the query is wrong

Comment: "desired tables..." Which tables would those be?

Comment: `exec sp_tables where table_name like '%desired%'`

Comment: The query is a simple example, as it is i the above code it works.
Below is what i think it should be.

Comment: `Select Column From yourTable`

Comment: @Dan Wilson i think that´s it. what i have is: `SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%test1%', '%test2%', '%test3%'"`
But still i get an error in the query

Comment: what error are you getting

Comment: @MethodMan the error i get is: Additional information: Incorrect syntax near ','.

Comment: because you can not separate `LIKE STATEMENT with commas it's telling you what the problem is.. do some reading up on SQL `LIKE CLAUSE` so change it to be use one LIKE for example either `LIKE '%test'` or `LIKE 'test%` or read up on how to use the `IN CLAUSE` but LIKE should do the trick for you..

Comment: I will edit my answer with how to do it give me a minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ORACLE this is how I would get a list of all tables that Start withj the Word `ANALYSIS` for Example

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME
FROM ALL_OBJECTS
WHERE OBJECT_TYPE = 'TABLE'
AND OBJECT_NAME LIKE 'ANALYSIS%';
```

In SQL Server you could follow the same Construct

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_CATALOG LIKE'test%'
```

Or use the `IN CLAUSE`

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_NAME IN ('t1','t2','t3' )
```

Comment: I tried several combinations of what you suggest but still not working.
imagine have 4 tables but only want to display 2 of them that are called table and laptop, how can i filter so that only these two are displayed?
My previous table names were wrong sorry.

Comment: @MethodMan that will giving table names of all databases.

Comment: i got it, thanks for the tips. i used: SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME IN ('t1','t2','t3' )

Comment: not a problem glad that I was able to quickly figure out what it is you were talking about.. in the future try to add all information errors etc that pertain to your problem and or issue so that we won't have to all guess cheers..!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could create a List of the "desired" table names, and then just check if "reader["TABLE_NAME"]" is in your list of OK tables, OR use the SQL "IN" statement.

Comment: LIKE STATEMENT would be better in regards to using Sql Wild Cards.. but the example in the OP comment / sql statement looks correct and actually if the table names contain the word `test` then only one LIKE clause would be needed not 3